# Swift IBAction Iteration

Tags: ios, swift

I think i have been coding for to many hours and i am getting delirious. I need a second eye to view my obvious problems.

-My function called **( @IBAction func SignIn )** at the bottom of the code ends after a single click. I click once works fine, click twice the code gets terminated and is done. How can I re-iterate this function so I can have it keep going every time I click the IB action button.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import KeychainSwift


class SignUpController: UIViewController {

    //Variable List
    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //Data Base Initialization
    public var validPassword = false        //Both passwords match

    //Represent Red or Green password Image
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    //INPUT - User Input from UI Text Fields
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirmField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField : UITextField!

    /****************************View Loads*****************************/

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "confirmPaswordRed")
    }

    //PROCESS - Checks is user has already been logged in
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        if currentUser != nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    /******************************************************************/





    /****************************Functions*****************************/

    func CompleteSignIn(id: String){
        let keyChain = DataService().keyChain
        keyChain.set(id , forKey: "uid")
    }

    //Send all data text fields to Firebase Database
    func sendToFirebaseDatabase(userID : String) {

        let name : String = self.nameField.text!
        let username : String = self.usernameField.text!
        let userEmail : String = self.emailField.text!
        let userPassword : String = self.passwordField.text!
        self.ref.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["Name": name, "Username": username, "Email": userEmail, "Password" : userPassword])
    }



    //Determines Red or Green password validation
    @IBAction func passwordConfirmImage(_ sender: UITextField) {

        let userConfirmPassword : String? = self.passwordConfirmField.text!
        let userPassword : String? = self.passwordField.text!

        if (userPassword == userConfirmPassword) && (userPassword != "") {

        validPassword = true
        let greenImage = UIImage(named: "confirmPasswordGreen")
        myImageView.image = greenImage
        print("Function entry test")

        }else {
            myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "confirmPaswordRed")
            validPassword = false
        }



    }

    /******************************************************************/




    /****************************IBACTIONS*****************************/







    //If SignUp button is pressed user will be directed to sign up page
    @IBAction func LoginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToLogin", sender: nil)
    }

    /*Sign In Action: If both password and email contain text lets put them into string variables
                      called email & password. Creates user and authorizes sign in                                      */

    @IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any){




        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {



                  FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                if ((error == nil) && (self.validPassword) == true) {



                    self.CompleteSignIn(id: user!.uid) //Completes Database Sign in
                    print("Sign in Test")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)


                } else {
                    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                        if ((error == nil) && (self.validPassword) == false) {

                        Alerts().invalidSignUpAlert(sender: self) //Alert for invalid email & Password

                            print("cant sign in user") //Programmer Debugging



                        } else  {

                            if self.validPassword == true{

                                let userID : String = user!.uid //initialize userId String
                                self.sendToFirebaseDatabase(userID: userID) //Call sendToFirebaseDatabase
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil) //goto Login Page

                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In other words how can i restart my class before the class is finished being executed

Comment: I think that's the more basic issue going on here - a class isn't *executed* (that's called top-down processing), a class is *instantiated*. As long as your view with that login button is visible, it can be clicked and processed.

Comment: Keep in mind: This `Signup` class should not be checking if the user is login or not, I would do the checking in the AppDelegate `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions`... To show correct image for password just use computed var instead of IBAction

Comment: It processes completely fine. However, when the button is clicked for a second time nothing is executed(When it dosnt process). I need it to re-execute the IBAction

Comment: Again, once a user signs in, then? Does it segue to another view (and controller)? That's sounds good and I see something like that in your code. So then? You unwind-segue to the login. Everything should work. So. What's the issue? What sequence of actions isn't working? If the first login isn't correct - for whatever reason - is *that* the issue?